# slick 3 joinLeft with None row

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Tried to select data from 2 tables

User and Task

Want to get all users without any tasks

tried next query

```
val fq = userQ.joinLeft(taskQ).filter(el => el._2.isEmpty)
```

Logically it is correct "select all users whick task field is empty"

bat result is 0. What I`ve done wrong ? any advices ?

Tables:

```
userQ
id------name

taskQ
id-----userId
```

BR!

Comment: What are `userQ` and `taskQ`. Can you give the table definition ?

Comment: sure, please see 'Tables'

Comment: I meant, the Scala definition so that I can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your query is missing on what to join :

`(userQ.joinLeft(taskQ).on(_.id === _.userId)).filter { case (user, task) => task.isEmpty }`

Comment: Tried have got NoSuchElementException None.get. I think this is does not work with .filter { case (user, task) => task.isEmpty }